# Kvlang cannot find id from dynamic widget class, KeyError

Tags: python, kivy

So I have a dynamic kvlang file like

```
<LeftSideButtonPanel@BoxLayout>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    size_hint_min: 200, 20
    size_hint_max: 300, 20
    Label:
        id: nickname
        text: "NICKNAME_NOT_FOUND"
        font_size: 18

<Connected>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        LeftSideButtonPanel:
        Label:
            id: another_name
            text: "EMPTY"
```

and main.py

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.11.1')
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, Builder

Builder.load_file("screens.kv")
class Connected(Screen):
    def on_enter(self):
        self.ids['nickname'].text = "NICKNAMEGOESHERE"
        self.ids['another_name'].text = "ANOTHERNAMEHERE"


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager()

        sm.add_widget(Connected(name="connected"))

        return sm

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

That I am inserting inside another boxlayout, and I am trying to change the nickname field once the user has authenticated, but for some reason I cannot find the Label with `.ids['nickname']`. Giving error `KeyError: 'nickname'`, but if I was to manually make a Label inside the other boxlayout with, I would find it `another_name` in example. Calling it from `on_enter` event handler.

ERROR MESSAGE:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "c:/Users/Ranta/Projects/Python/testing/KivyTesting/main.py", line 24, in <module>
     MyApp().run()
   File "C:\Users\Ranta\Projects\Python\testing\KivyTesting\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 829, in run
     root = self.build()
   File "c:/Users/Ranta/Projects/Python/testing/KivyTesting/main.py", line 19, in build
     sm.add_widget(Connected(name="connected"))
   File "C:\Users\Ranta\Projects\Python\testing\KivyTesting\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\screenmanager.py", line 992, in add_widget
     self.current = screen.name
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 497, in kivy.properties.Property.__set__
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 544, in kivy.properties.Property.set
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 599, in kivy.properties.Property.dispatch
   File "C:\Users\Ranta\Projects\Python\testing\KivyTesting\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\screenmanager.py", line 1055, in on_current
     screen.dispatch('on_enter')
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "c:/Users/Ranta/Projects/Python/testing/KivyTesting/main.py", line 11, in on_enter
     self.ids['nickname'].text = "this"
 KeyError: 'nickname'
```

Comment: improve your indentation, provide  a [mre] and show the **complete** error message.

Comment: unrelated. .. but i would avoid kvlang in general in favor of making everything from classes ... I think it is much easier and better documented and less magic (just my 2c ... )

Comment: @eyllanesc here you go.

Comment: @Lauri what is the filename of .kv?

Comment: im using Builder.load_file("screens.kv")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ids are accessed through root, in your case for example "another_name" is rooted to "Connected" so use `self.ids['another_name'].text =" ANOTHERNAMEHERE "` works because self is the instance of "Connected" but "nickname" is not rooted to "Connected" but to "LeftSideButtonPanel" so you must first access that instance and for that you must set an id:

```
# ...
<Connected>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        LeftSideButtonPanel:
            id: left_panel
        Label:
            id: another_name
            text: "EMPTY"
```

```
class Connected(Screen):
    def on_enter(self):
        self.ids["left_panel"].ids["nickname"].text = "NICKNAMEGOESHERE"
        # or
        # self.ids.left_panel.ids.nickname.text = "NICKNAMEGOESHERE"
        self.ids["another_name"].text = "ANOTHERNAMEHERE"
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you very much.